# Matching property from array of objects in MongoDB aggregation query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

In mongoDB I have collection where field 'abc' is array of objects like this:

```
'abc': [{"_id": new ObjectId("someId"), "name": "entity name"}]
```

I want to make **aggregation** (it cannot be .find()) where I pass value to match _id property

Something like this does not work

```
{ $match: { 'abc._id': { $in: ['someId', 'someId2']} }}
```

I tried multiple ways I found on Internet but nothing worked.

Does anyone know how to do this using aggregate function?

Comment: In what way does it not work? An error, incorrect results, something else? Have you tried using the same data type? It looks like you have strings in your `$in` list currently but the documents use ObjectIds there instead. Also not that it makes any difference, but why can't you use `find()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, [**Aggregate**](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/aggregation/) takes an array.

**Solution:**
You must wrap ids with Mongo [**ObjectId**](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/).

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
const ids = ['someId1', 'someId2'].map(id => ObjectId(id))
const pipeline = [{$match: {_id: {$in: ids }}}]

<your model>.aggregate(pipeline, (err, docs) => console.log({err, docs}))
```

Comment: You are right! Wrapping with ObjectId worked. I assumed that this should not be a problem and did not try this. Thank you!